# Помогите пожалуйста. Не понимаю в чём проблема

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Я только начал учить C#.
Решил использовать Visual Studio Code.
Но столкнулся с данной проблемой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за данной проблемы не могу дальше учить c# . 
Вот код если что.

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello 
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по вcему, у вас Windows, поставьте Visual Studio Community, он лучше подходит для этой цели. А что у вас с кодировкой - не понятно.

Comment: Лучше для новичка юзать VS Community  а так воспользуйтесь этой инструкцией https://pikabu.ru/story/c_urok_1_ustanovka_visual_studio_code_6987987